# Distinct count of cells ignoring merged cells included - speed problem

Tags: excel, vba

Imagine scenario:
[image]

all the yellow cells have a formula.

Now I want to have the count of the cells with a formula but e.g. I4:J8 should only count for 2.

The following code shows some possibilities - some are just wrong.
But the idea should be clear:
Getting all cells from a range where a merged area should count only as one cell.
But without touching each cell. I tried a lot of things, which are much better then the code below (analyzing the mergearea of a cell and then ignoring parts of it by row column analysis) but I would like, if someone has a good idea for that.

And imagine you have a range with a million of cells.
And the formula thing is only an example, there are many situations you want to have the distinct count.

```
 Public Sub Example()
        Dim ar As Range
        Dim count As Long
        Dim RealCount As Long
        Dim ra As Range, ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
        Set ra = ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        Debug.Print ra.Address
        For Each ar In ra.Areas
            If ar.Cells(1, 1).MergeArea.Address = ar.Address Then
                count = count + 1
            Else
                count = count + ar.Cells.count
            End If
        Next
        RealCount = GetCountRealSlowButCorrect(ra)
        Debug.Print "count by me but bad: "; count; " cells count: "; ra.Cells.count; " RealCount: "; RealCount
    End Sub
    
    Private Function GetCountRealSlowButCorrect(ra As Range) As Long
        Dim g As Range
        Dim su As Long
        su = ra.Cells.count
        For Each g In ra
            If g = g.MergeArea.Cells(1, 1) Then
                su = su - (g.MergeArea.Cells.count - 1)
            End If
        Next
        GetCountRealSlowButCorrect = su
    End Function
```

Comment: How about:  `For Each g In ra.Areas: su = su + Application.CountA(g): Next`

Comment: @TimWilliams OMG so simple and good. Just use excel to do the job :-) CountA does the job even when a formula returns an empty string.
I go back to the formula school. Tx for open my glued eyes :-)

Comment: @TimWilliams Now I have to formulate a new question with xlCellTypeAllFormatConditions or other like xlCellTypeAllValidation where this will not help, because of empty cells. But for the moment formulas is what I Am mostly interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my version - should be relatively OK performance-wise:

```vb
'set up a large range with merged cells
Sub Setup()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = [A1:J20] 'contains some merged cells
    Do While rng.Row < 20000
        rng.Copy rng.Offset(rng.Rows.count)
        Set rng = rng.Offset(rng.Rows.count)
    Loop
End Sub

Sub Tester()
    
    Dim rngT As Range, rng As Range, c As Range, t, m As Range, n As Long
    
    Set rng = [A1:J19]
    Set rngT = [A1:J19]
    'creating a large range object with multiple areas and merged cells
    Do While rng.Row < 20000
        Set rngT = Application.Union(rngT, rng.Offset(20))
        Set rng = rng.Offset(20)
    Loop
    Debug.Print rngT.Areas.count & " areas", rngT.Cells.count & " cells (ignoring merges)"
    
    t = Timer
    'start counting
    For Each c In rngT.Cells
        Set m = c.mergeArea
        If m.count > 1 Then
            'only count if this is the top-left cell of the merge
            If c.Address = m(1).Address Then n = n + 1
        Else
            n = n + 1 'not merged
        End If
    Next c
    Debug.Print Round(Timer - t, 2) & " sec", n & " cells (accounting for merges)"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: And again a super code I will take it as answer.
It has some flaws when the range has no merges or only a few, because it still iterates.
But in Excel it is fast enough.
I'm a bit interop harmed so I always try not to access the cells if possible, but in VBA this is not a problem. I will test it against interop to see, if it works as fine then I think I will try a combination (Checking for merge = null and then iterating)
TX again

Comment: Just for fun: B1 to B3 merged and checking the range A3:C3
This is an unlikely scenario - but shows an other flaw.
It will take time for me, to check it with interop but I will show the result when ever I got time to do the check.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will count what you need:

```
Sub CountCells()
   Dim counter As Long
   With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
      counter = .Count
      On Error Resume Next
      counter = counter - .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
      On Error GoTo 0
      counter = counter - WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Cells)
      Debug.Print counter
   End With
End Sub
```

This code is valid when **all merged areas contain formulas**.
If this condition is not met, you can use the following code:

```
Sub CountCellsX()
    Dim cell As Range, counter As Long
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
         If cell.HasFormula Then counter = counter + 1
    Next cell
    Debug.Print counter
End Sub
```

Comment: The iteration through each cell is what I didn't want. Imagine there are 1 Million formula cells or more.

Comment: In the first proposal there are no iterations. And you declared that all merged cells contain formulas. So it should be good for you.

Answer (score 0):

After @TimWilliams put the shame on my head by giving a simple solution for formula cells i got deeper into it to find a more common solution for this problem and in the end I came to following solution to get a cell count of a range with counting merged cells as only one cell, regardless how the range is set.
And I want to share it with the community.
I hope I looked at all possible failures but there could still be some.
If you find some errors, please give a comment

I put the working code into a Class with the name clsDistinctCellCountMerge:

```
Option Explicit
' Class clsDistinctCellCountMerge
' if the cells count can exceed long, then a few things have to be changed
' But I think, then something is anyway on fire
'theRange: the Range to get the count from

Public Function GetDistinctCellCount(theRange As Range) As Long
    Dim area As Range
    Dim count As Long
    For Each area In theRange.Areas
        count = count + GetAreaCount(area)
    Next area
    GetDistinctCellCount = count
End Function

Private Function GetAreaCount(area As Range) As Long
    Dim mergeCheck As Variant
    mergeCheck = area.MergeCells
    If IsNull(mergeCheck) Then
        GetAreaCount = GetCellCountDistinctMerge(area)
    Else
        If mergeCheck Then
            GetAreaCount = 1
        Else
            GetAreaCount = area.Cells.count
        End If
    End If
End Function
' Analyse of an area which has merged cells

Private Function GetCellCountDistinctMerge(area As Range) As Long
    Dim rowsOnBlock As Long
    Dim i As Long, k As Long, m As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim cellCount As Long
    Dim mergeCheck As Variant
    Dim mergeArea As Range
    Dim checks() As Boolean
    Dim rr As Long, cc As Long
    Dim rowCount As Long, columnCount As Long
    rowCount = area.Rows.count
    columnCount = area.Columns.count
    rowsOnBlock = Fix(rowCount / 20)
    If rowsOnBlock = 0 Then rowsOnBlock = 5
    Dim rowIgnore() As Boolean
    ReDim rowIgnore(rowCount)
    If rowCount > rowsOnBlock Then
        For i = 1 To rowCount Step rowsOnBlock
            lRow = i + rowsOnBlock - 1
            If lRow > rowCount Then lRow = rowCount
            mergeCheck = area.Rows((i) & ":" & lRow).MergeCells
            If IsNull(mergeCheck) Then
            Else
                If mergeCheck Then
                    cellCount = cellCount + 1
                    For m = i To lRow
                        rowIgnore(m) = True
                    Next
                Else
                    For m = i To lRow
                        rowIgnore(m) = True
                        cellCount = cellCount + columnCount
                    Next
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
    ReDim checks(1 To rowCount, 1 To columnCount)
    Dim rp As Long
    Dim cp As Long
    For i = 1 To rowCount
        If Not rowIgnore(i) Then
            For k = 1 To columnCount
                If Not checks(i, k) Then
                    cellCount = cellCount + 1
                    Set mergeArea = area.Cells(i, k).mergeArea
                    If mergeArea.Cells.count > 1 Then
                        For rr = 1 To mergeArea.Rows.count
                            rp = i + rr - 1
                            For cc = 1 To mergeArea.Columns.count
                                cp = k + cc - 1
                                If rp <= rowCount And cp <= columnCount Then
                                    checks(rp, cp) = True
                                End If
                            Next cc
                        Next rr
                    Else
                    End If
                End If
            Next k
        End If
    Next i
    GetCellCountDistinctMerge = cellCount
End Function
```

My Testszenario:
[image]

The call is from a common module like:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMergeCount()
    Dim ra As Range
    Dim myMerge As New clsDistinctCellCountMerge
    Set ra = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ra = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    If Not ra Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Formulas"
        Debug.Print ra.Address
        Debug.Print myMerge.GetDistinctCellCount(ra)
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Debug.Print "Just Cells"
    Set ra = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:K18")
    Debug.Print ra.Address
    Debug.Print myMerge.GetDistinctCellCount(ra)
    Set ra = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:K17") ' critical cause it does not include complete merge
    Debug.Print ra.Address
    Debug.Print myMerge.GetDistinctCellCount(ra)
End Sub
```